# HAP won't work for one specific URL

Tags: html-agility-pack

I've simplified my code to the following method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ViaplayCrawl()
{
    var getWeb = new HtmlWeb();
    var documentUrl = getWeb.Load("http://viaplay.dk/");
    var someVar = documentUrl.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body").Count;
}
```

This method works for all other webpages I've tried, but it seems to fail for "viaplay.dk"

I get a NullReferenceException when I assign someVar a value.

Anyone have an Idea how I can crawl viaplay.dk using htmlagilitypackage?

Comment: @Uwe I see you're on an editing spree. Can you please fix _all_ errors with the posts you're editing?

Comment: @CodeCaster Which am I missing?

Comment: @Uwe in this case: "HtmlAgilityPack - HAP" is used as a tag in the title, "specifik" has a typo.

Comment: @CodeCaster OK. Actually I changed all "NullReferencException" → "NullReferenceException" in 15 posts and did not look left or right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site doesn't return a `content-type` header, which is a cue for the `HtmlWeb` class to ignore the result.

This is the method responsible:

> HtmlAgilityPack.dll!HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get(System.Uri uri, string method, string path, HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc, System.Net.IWebProxy proxy, System.Net.ICredentials creds) Line 216   C#

[image]

If you use the `HttpClient` class and feed the content to the `Document.LoadHtml` class that should work. Or ask the owner of the site to return a proper header.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var result = client.GetStringAsync("http://viaplay.dk/").Result;

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(result);

var someVar = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body").Count;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already experimented with stream and selenium web driver in order to get the Html and use document.load(response). I'll look into your ansver tomorrow, thank you for your time